# Convert JSON to CSV with multiple keys

Tags: python, json, csv

I writing a code to convert JSON file to CSV. This script works but not with multiple keys in JSON.

I had the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 27, in <module>
    for j in data[i]:
KeyError: 0
```

Could you help me?

```
import os
import csv
import json,requests
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import defaultdict
headers = {
  ****
  ****
}
response = requests.get('https://www.exemple.com', headers=headers)
data = response.json()
#print (data)
#print("JSON file loaded")
        # get all keys in json objects
keys = []
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    for j in data[i]:
        if j not in keys:
           keys.append(j)

# map data in each row to key index
converted = []
converted.append(keys)
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    row = []
    for j in range(0,len(keys)):
        if keys[j] in data[i]:
            row.append(data[i][keys[j]])
        else:
            row.append(None)
    converted.append(row)
    
with open("filename.csv", 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(converted)
```

Comment: I think you have to provide the website you get the JSON from or provide some sort of JSON file with which the error occurs. Otherwise, nobody can recreate your problem and help you.

Comment: I agree. It's unlikely anyone can help you unless you provide a runnable [mre]. This is especially important because the answer probably depends on the input (and what you mean by "multiple keys").

Comment: It works with a simple json file:


[{
        "pk": 22,
        "model": "auth.permission",
        "fields": {
            "codename": "add_logentry",
            "name": "Can add log entry",
            "content_type": 8
    }, 
    }
]

Comment: Hi hazzouz, you can use the [edit] button to make improvements and additions to your question (don't add an answer just for extra info)

Comment: Are you hoping to write a single script to convert all kinds of different JSON to CSV?

Comment: Just incidentally, don't write `for i in range(len(some_dict)): some_dict[i]`. Use `for value in some_dict.values(): value` instead. Might find this useful: https://youtu.be/qUeud6DvOWI

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug here:

```py
keys = []
for i in range(0,len(data)): #data is a `dict` 
    for j in data[i]: # <-- error: i is an int, not a key in your data
        if j not in keys:
           keys.append(j)
```

If you want to get the top-level keys in a `dict`, the `dict` can just give it to you:

```py
for key in my_dict:
    print(key)
```

But it looks like you're trying to get the values from your `data`. `dict` can give you this too:

```py
for value in my_dict.values():
    print(value)
```

Or you can get both at the same time:

```py
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
```